# It is possible to send files by the put method in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to send a file by PUT method on Angular but the file always goes empty. I searched about and it seems that file is only sent if I use the formData, but the PUT method in the API does not receive any information that is sent as formData. Is there another possibility to send this file?

Comment: What does the API expect to get?

Comment: Can you share your upload source code, and that of the API if you have it?

Comment: the API waiting x-www-form-urlencoded.